# Difference between "surely die" between Genesis 2:17 and 1 Kings 2:42

Tags: genesis, hebrew, hebrew-bible

I noticed that the phrase "surely die" in Genesis 2:17 is different from 1 Kings 2:42

Look at the hebrew letters in both of them (I found it kinda difficult to copy past them here):

http://biblehub.com/interlinear/genesis/2-17.htm

http://biblehub.com/interlinear/1_kings/2-42.htm

They are not exactly the same. Does that change their meaning? Or do both of them stil mean the same thing as the english translation?

Comment: Try changing 'interlinear' to 'text' in the URL. Thank me later.

Comment: The words look exactly the same. We have מות תמות in both verses, with the same vowels. Where's the problem?

Comment: Well, for example, in Genesis the left-most character of the word "die" is a semi-colon looking thing. And the vowels are slightly different in 3th character from the left.

Comment: @WatchHat those are cantillation signs/notes, not vowelization/letters.  While the cantillation notes are sometimes used to break up phrases, here they would not change the meaning.

Comment: @רבותמחשבות - that sounds like the start of a good answer...

Comment: A discussion about the similar meaning/implications of these two verses and many similar verses that use the same expression can be found in [this answer](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/a/8802/2070).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, welcome to BH and thanks for the question!

In this case, although there are some visual differences, they do have the exact same Hebrew terms.

In Hebrew, the vowels are called Nikkud or Nekudot, and they play a very significant role in how we understand (and translate) a word.  The Nekudot here are identical.  You can see a list of Nekudot [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Niqqud#Demonstration).  However, the Te'amim, or Cantillation notes are different.  You can see a list [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantillation#Names_and_shapes_of_the_te%27amim).

In [Genesis 2:17](http://biblehub.com/interlinear/genesis/2-17.htm), the verse shows:

> ## מ֥וֹת תָּמֽוּת

In [1 Kings 2:42](http://biblehub.com/interlinear/1_kings/2-42.htm):

> ## מ֣וֹת תָּמ֑וּת

There are 2 visible differences between these, the sign under the first letter (if we read right-to-left, the direction that Hebrew text is read in), and the sign under the third to last letter.  Both are differences in the Te'amim (and you are welcome to match them up to the list linked above).

---

Some notes:

- It should be noted that Te'amim can sometimes have an impact on the translation of the words, as they also show how to "break up" terms, as well as how to pronounce them, which can also change the tense of the words (past/present/future).
- Technically speaking, this term does not technically mean "surely die", but rather both Hebrew words are from the root of death. (See Young's literal translation [here](http://biblehub.com/genesis/2-17.htm).)  See [here](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/a/32294/22655) for a nice explanation of this phenomenon.